# Image upload not placing Image in Server Folder

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I am having trouble with uploading an Image to my server files.
I am building an online store where, when i add a product, a can select an image for it to.
I have checked my php.ini file to allow uploads, as well as sufficient size of file allowed.
I have set the permissions to the folder where the images are supposed to go to "full control" for "Everyone"
(just to avoid any problems there)

I have one physical PC with multiple small drives.
Only one drive has my web server files.
The others have Minecraft and TeamSpeak.

The PC is in a room next to my office at home on a local network.
I could upload the images manually with file browser or FTP but,
In the near future there will not only be me uploading and adding products to the store locally.

Now, when i open my add product page there is a "Upload Image" button next to a text field,
that opens a separate window containing the upload page code.
The text field is to link the image on my database.

So I click on the "Upload Image" button and  the following happens:
Small separate window appears with 2 buttons, Browse and Upload.
I click on browse, and select my image.
The image name now displays next to the browse button.
When I click Upload, it closes the page, the image name displays in the text field next to the "Upload Image"
button in the product adding list for database reference.
I click on add product, and the product , including the image name displays on the database.

But the image did not upload to the specified server folder.

I have tried inserting the entire file path...
"D:/Web/shop/graphics/products"
Didn't work.
(D:/Web.. is the drive and root folder with the website content)

WEB FOLDER STRUCTURE:
`Web-->
      [main_page_images]
      [shop_root]-->
                    [shop_admin]-->
                                   [shop_images]-->
                                                   [products]-->
                                                   (where the image should go)
                    index.php
                    add_product.php
                    add_image.php
      index.php
      web.config`
(there are some other folders in the structure but they are not relevant)

add_image.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>CompuShop Image Chooser</title>
</head><body>   
<?php if ((isset($_POST["send"])) && ($_POST["send"] == "form1")) {
    $file_Name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], "../shop_images/products".$file_Name);
?>
<script>
    opener.document.form1.strImage.value="<?php echo $file_Name; ?>";
    self.close();
</script>
<?php
}
else
{?>
<form action="add_image.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1" />
<p>
    <input name="userfile" type="file">
</p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Upload Image" />
</p>
    <input type="hidden" name="send" value="form1" />
</form>
<?php }?>
</body>
</html>
```

Now that I have give all the Info i posably can...

Am I missing something?
Am I doing something wrong?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question today coz I can.

I'm not exactly shoor how I fixed this but it is working. (please reply if you know the solution)

I went through some other posts and one of them mentioned settings in my PhP config itself.
the latest PhP upload settings are by default...

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
; http://php.net/file-uploads
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
; http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir
;upload_tmp_dir =

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 2M

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20
```

So I changed it to...

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
; http://php.net/file-uploads
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
; http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir
upload_tmp_dir = D:/Web/temp

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 2048MB

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20
```

I first changed the "upload_max_filesize" to 1024MB
Did not work.
Then to 2048MB
Same result.
Now here is what I think did the trick...
I then specify the "upload_tmp_dir" and it is uploading now.

My page code just for reference...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Shop Database Image Chooser</title>
</head><body>   
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

 if ((isset($_POST["send"])) && ($_POST["send"] == "form1")) {
    $file_Name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], "../shop_images/products/".$file_Name);
    ?>
    <script>
        opener.document.form1.strImage.value="<?php echo $file_Name; ?>";
        self.close();
    </script>
<?php
}
else
{?>
<form action="image_adding.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1" />
<p>
    <input name="userfile" type="file">
</p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Upload Image" />
</p>
    <input type="hidden" name="send" value="form1" />
</form>
<?php }?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thx to the guys from phphelp.com for all the patiance.

Answer (score 1):

try to put `/` on your `move_uploaded_file` function and i think you dont need `..`

`move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], "/shop_images/products/".$file_Name);`

Comment: I attempted with the [..] and with out, as well as with the [/] and without.

Comment: Dose anyone have any other ideas?